# Linear Differential Equations word problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I had this quiz on LDE and I wasn't sure how to do this problem...I know how to do LDE but I couldn't come up with the equation to get me started. Any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start. Recalling the Newton's second law

> $$ F = m a = m\frac{dv}{dt}. $$

where $m$ is the mass and $a$ is the acceleration. Now, when you throw the rock vertically upward, the gravity $g$ and the resistance of the air $r$ will act downward. that results in the equation

$$  m\frac{dv}{dt}= -g - r .$$

Now, you have a differential equation with initial condition $v(0)=20$.

**Notes:**

i) The speed at maximum height is $0$.

ii) The distance $s(t)$ is related to velocity with the relation

> $$ v(t)=\frac{ds(t)}{dt}. $$

Comment: @Mhennie Benghorbal Guys this isn't a homework questions so you could tell me how to do this because it was on a previous quiz and I couldn't fiugre it out which is why I am trying to understand the solution.

Comment: Thank you @Daryl and Mhenni Benghorbal . Both your solutions contributed to my understanding. One thing Daryl that should be noted in your solution is that mg should be -mg so you would get -mg - v^2/10 and then you can integrate velocity function to get the values needed. To get the velocity function though you need to integrate the dv/dt = -g - r formula.

Comment: @Raynos: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to get started.

1. Let down be the negative direction, so that $g=-9.81$.
2. Let $v$ be the velocity of the rock.
3. Use Newton's Second Law $F=ma$ to derive a linear ODE which the velocity satisfies.
4. Given: $m=1$ is given, $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$ and $v(0)=20$.
5. What forces are acting on the rock after it has been released (Hint: gravity $mg$ and air resistance $-\dfrac{v^2}{10}$)? How strong are these forces?

**Edit in response to comment:**

The forces acting on the rock are assumed to only be gravity and air resistance (in the absence of additional information), so that $F=mg-\dfrac{v^2}{10}$.

This gives the IVP
$$
m\frac{dv}{dt}=mg-\frac{1}{10}v^2,\, v(0)=20.
$$
The solution of this problem models the velocity of the rock.

Comment: this isn't a homework questions so you could tell me how to do this because it was on a previous quiz and I couldn't fiugre it out which is why I am trying to understand the solution.

Comment: @Raynos Sure. I will extend my answer to include the ODE.