# Differential Equation - Falling Projectile - Help getting started?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Here is the question I'm dealing with:

A ball with mass 0.15 kg is thrown upward with initial velocity 20 m/s from the roof of a
building 30 m high.  There is a force due to air resistance of magnitude |v|/30 directed opposite to the velocity, where the velocity v is measured in m/s.

**Find the time that the ball hits the ground.**

NOTE: I have calculated the highest height the ball reaches: it is 45.783 m

---

m dV/dt = -mg + V/30

dV/dt = -g + V/30m

dV/dt = (-30mg + V)/30m

dV/(-30mg + V) = dt/30m

ln(-30mg + V) = t/30m + C

e^(ln(-30mg + V)) = e^(t/30m + C)

-30mg + V = e ^(t/30m + C)

V = Ce^(t/30m) + 30mg

*Since the projectile is instantaneously at rest, V(0) = 0

Therefore, C = -30mg

So:

V = 30mg - 30mg*e^(t/30m)

Now to integrate to get our position function:

X = 30mg*t - (30m)^2*g*e^(t/30m) + C

Since X at t = 0 is 45.783 m, C is equal to (30m)^2*g

I know that setting X= 0 will tell me the time at which the projectile hits the ground, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to arrive at an answer for t without just going to Wolfram Alpha.

Is there a better way for me to be attempting what I'm attempting?

I apologize for not having proper formatting for my work.

Thanks!

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576805/linear-differential-equations-word-problem).

Comment: Mhenni - I appreciate the reply, but the issue that I am having is more related to the projectile's journey on the way down.  I have already arrived at the solution for the journey upwards.

Comment: Make sure you got the right equation.

Comment: Mhenni - Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Is $\,m\dot v=-mg+v/30\,$ the right equation ? I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for $v$ (see my comment above) is $$m\dot v=-mg-kv$$Let $v=\dot y$.
Then$$y=y_0-\frac{mg}kt+\frac mk\left(v_0+\frac{mg}k\right)\left(1-e^{-\frac kmt}\right)$$Given $y_0=30$ and $v_0=20$, one solves (by a numerical method) $$y=0$$with rspect to $t$ and finds $t=5.1285 s$ .